# CMake: Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS always set to /usr/include

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I want to use Boost in one of my CMake projects. I have added the line `find_package(Boost 1.40 REQUIRED)` to the main CMakeLists.txt file. This works fine except that subsequently `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is set to `/usr/include` and not `/usr/include/boost` or even `/usr/include/boost/SOME_COMPONENT` if I use `find_package(Boost 1.40 REQUIRED COMPONENTS SOME_COMPONENT)` instead.

The documentation does not help at all here, is this intended behaviour or some sort of bug? I'm on Linux and I'm using `cmake 3.11.4`.

Comment: What is wrong in this include directory (`/usr/include`)? You should use `#include <boost/[component]/[header].hpp>` for include a header file from the Boost 1.40. Like here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/math/doc/gcd/html/gcd_and_lcm/gcd_lcm/header.html.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think I was confused by the fact that the variable is named ...DIRS and not ...DIR so I thought it might expand to the directories containing the relevant header files but on second thought that would not be very useful.